# C pointer arithmetic segmentation fault only inside of for loop

Tags: c

I am trying to write a function that checks if a number is a palindrome or not. (project euler). I decided to write a function that converts the number to a string and uses two pointers to iterate forward and backward through the string. However, I keep getting a segmentation fault when trying to add to the pointers inside of the for loop.

```
int isPalindromeNumber(int number)
{
    char* str;
    itoa(number, str, 10);
    int length = strlen(str);
    int isPalindrome = 1;

    char* forwardPtr = str;
    char* backwardPtr = str + (length - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
    {
        if (*forwardPtr != *backwardPtr)
        {
            isPalindrome = 0;
        }

        // Segfault here.
        forwardPtr += 1;
        backwardPtr -= 1;
    }

    return isPalindrome;
}
```

However, if I try to increment/decrement these pointers before the for loop, there is no problem. I've tried limiting the for loop to only one iteration as well, and it still segfaults.

I get the feeling this is a simple problem but I can't seem to find any question similar to this. So any help or redirection is appreciated!

Comment: you need to allocate memory for `str`

Comment: I'm slightly surprised that the crash doesn't happen right on the `itoa()` call, but that's undefined behavior for you.

Comment: @FredLarson tomorrow it probably will crash there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
  char* str;
```

to

```
 char str[11];
```

In your code you have a pointer to nowhere. This change makes a local buffer large enough to hold string version of 32 bit interger

Comment: When represented in base-10, that is.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still kind of confused about how the code was working before though.. If I printed out the initial dereferenced values of those two pointers, it produced the expected values. I also tried adding and subtracting and it worked as well. Do you happen to know why that occured?

Comment: welcome to the world of Undefined Behavior, try changing hte order of declaration of things in yr original code, the behavior will change. (Move int length before char * str, see what happens)

Answer (score 0):

No need to complicate the program you can easily do this by storing your number in any other variable in reverse order and then compare both variable

But, still i respect your question and i think you are trying to learn about pointer so i will help you with this

```
    #include<stdio.h>
 ' int main(){
         char string[40];
         char *ptr,*rev;
         clrscr();
         printf("\nGive a string : ");
         gets(string);
         ptr=string;
         while(*ptr!=NULL){
         ++ptr;
         }
         --ptr;
         for(rev=string; ptr>=rev;){
         if(*ptr == *rev)
         {
         --ptr;
         rev++;
         }
         else
         break;
         }
         if(rev>ptr)
         printf("\nThe given string %s is Palindrome",string);
         else
         printf("\nThe given string %s is not Palindrome",string);
         getch();
         return(0);
         } '

  It just a issue of memory allocation change *str to str[size] it will work
```